# Two column responsive issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am pretty new to coding in responsiveness. I usually use a wordpress theme that already has it working but I am doing a few edits to a site for someone and looking to fix their issue.

Basically there are two columns, one with float left and width: 65%, the right one with Float right and width of 30%. they scale to a point but then the right one drops down but stays beside the left one instead of under it

here is the page: http://engfind.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

#### Media queries

You want to stack them with 100% width on tablets or on mobiles devices -.

Example:considering breakpoint to be 600px

```
 @media (max-width: 600px){
      .homePage{
      width:100%;
      }
      .homeNews{
      width:100%;
      float:left;
      } 
      }
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get this to work. It's does not do anything, unless I am adding it improperly

Comment: i tried by changing properties in chrome dev tools but they are not reflecting ..none of your css properties seem to be editable by dev tools

Comment: I use firebug and it seems to take code generally. Not exactly sure what you were trying though.

Comment: I added !important to each of them and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Floating both of the divs `left` should do the trick. Make sure you apply `overflow:hidden` to the parent container or put a `clearfix` div below so that content below does not creep up.

Comment: Thanks, This will move the right bar under the left one but they will both stay the same size they are now. Trying to get them to fill width on mobile etc.

Comment: The you need to do conditional css using media queries to adjust the width to 100%

Comment: I'm not sure where to put that and what the code would be specifically. Never done media queries before.

Comment: Look at the answer by @SaiRamSudheer You need to add the media query in your CSS file that targets specific view widths. The one in his example targets all widths up to 600px.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added !important to his code and it worked.